# UDP c++ socket not reachable after few minutes android

Tags: android, c++, sockets, udp, keep-alive

I am using UDP sockets through C++ code and using NDK.
I have a constant ping-pong(keep-alive) mechanism to keep connection active in my protocol.

I have one thread which is constantly looking for incoming messages from server which is running infinitely.

```
while(true){
     ..... some code

     int llen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (const sockaddr *)&si_other, (socklen_t*)&slen);

     ..... some code 
}
```

Communication works good if I keep ping-pong time to **nearly 30 seconds** even if device is idle.

But if I put ping-pong time to 10 minutes, and if server sends some data at 7th minute. It not reaches to client (android device) even if ip/port of the device is same in idle state.

Notes :

- I have to keep ping-pong at 10 minutes.
- I am using Partial wake lock.
- I cannot use push notifications through firebase.
- Doze is not affecting as my app is whitelisted.
- I am also using AlarmManager to send ping-pong.

What can be the solution to the problem I am facing? Any idea will be good.

Comment: On line 311 there are gremlins dancing. You can prove me wrong with a [mcve].

Comment: You can't have UDP keep-alive time to 10 mins. NAT mapping may disappear by that time. In my opinion anything more than 30 sec is risky. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354131/for-how-long-a-router-keeps-records-in-the-nat-and-can-they-be-reused-forwarding

Comment: @taskinoor, so I guess I need to use TCP instead UDP ? But it may not possible.

Comment: TCP and UDP has different use cases. I can't tell whether TCP would serve your purpose.